# Saving user information to Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am new to Firebase and am currently  setting up user and user registration. I have got that working fine but I want to save user information to my firebase database. This is my register function

```
register: function(user){
        return simpleLogin.$createUser(user.email, user.password)       
        .then(function(regUser){    
            var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users');
            var firebaseUsers = $firebase(ref);

            var userInfo = {
                date: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
                regUser: regUser.uid,
                firstname: user.firstname,
                lastname: user.lastname,
                email: user.email
            }   
            firebaseUsers.$set(regUser.uid, userInfo);
        });//add user
    },//register
```

As you can see from the above, I have created a userInfo object that I want to add to my database. What I want to happen is that when you go into my database I have a tree structure of

user - uid - userinfo

Instead of the above I have users - and all you can see is the uid:

[image]

I have debugged the code and all the info is being properly saved to my userInfo object - its just doesn't seem to save to firebase properly

Comment: Instead of creating a `$firebase` wrapper and calling `$set`, can you simple try `ref.child(regUser.uid).set(userInfo)`? It bypasses AngularFire. Even if it still doesn't work, at least we'll know it's not related to AngularFire's `$firebast.$set` implementation.

Comment: That works perfectly -  Still a bit baffled as to why the set doesn't work. Thanks very much.

Comment: Didn't you recently ask the same question?

Comment: My reproduction also works fine here: http://jsbin.com/momoke/1/edit?js,output. I use the latest AngularFire, which is (IIRC) also exactly what Kato recommended on a previous question that looked suspiciously similar to this one.

Comment: Nope, this is the first time I have asked the question - only started using firebase a few days ago. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, as Frank has pointed out, the code you have above does not create the problem described.